# Pdf file is inserted in bad way

Tags: pdftex

I try to insert a .pdf file into the latex using a code:

```
\newpage
\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \includepdf[pages=-]{file1.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

but it is inserted only on one page (all pages of the .pdf are inserted on one page). How to improve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating objects like `figure` are limited to one page. Just remove the environment:

```
\newpage
\includepdf[pages=-]{file1.pdf}
```